# using pointer subscript inside an array

Tags: c, pointers

i wrote a program for counting sort using pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int max(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    int maxi=*arr;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(*(arr+i)>maxi)
            maxi=*(arr+i);
    }
    return maxi;
}
void count(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    int s=max(arr,n);
    printf("max %d",s);
    int c[s];
    memset(c,0,s*sizeof(int));
    int b[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        ++c[arr[i]];
    }
    for(i=1;i<s;++i)
    {
        c[i]=c[i]+c[i-1];
    }
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;--i)
        {
            b[c[arr[i]]]=arr[i];
            --c[arr[i]];
        }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
          arr[i]=b[i];
        }
}

void print(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\nelement is %d ",*(arr+i));

}

    int main()
    {
        int n,i;
        int *arr=malloc(n*sizeof(int));

        printf("\nenter the number of elements ");
        scanf("%d  ",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d",&arr[i]);

        count(arr,n);
        print(arr,n);
        return 0;
    }
```

as i debug the program it stops at `++c[arr[i]]` giving a segmentation fault. My call watches window looks like this[image: watches window]

my inputs were like this

```
enter the number of elements 4
1
3
5
7
max 7
```

the code received segmentation fault after this also, the value of i is initialized to 0,then why is the watches window showing it's value as 4. is it fine  to pass pointer subscripts to a static array or should i declare c dynamically?

Comment: Here `int *arr=malloc(n*sizeof(int));` the variable `n` is uninitialized. Move the line below the `scanf`

Comment: also in the `count` function. If `s` is the greates value in `arr` then you need an array with a length of `s + 1` so that `arr[s]` is valid. Also make sure that `arr` does not contain any negative numbers.

Comment: also note that `int c[s];` is a Variable Length Array (VLA), which is only valid in some versions of the C standard and has lots of pitfalls - as you are working with dynamic memory anyway, `malloc` would be better. (same for `int b[n];`)

Comment: OT: Sometimes you do `arr[i]` and sometimes you do `*(arr+i)`. They are the same so no real problem but consider being consistent about which to use

Comment: Also note that every `malloc` needs a corresponding `free`, or you will create a memory leak.

Comment: rather than `printf("\n.....blah blah blah....");` (which may be translated to english as "finish previous line and add stuff to a new, as of yet, unfinished line") prefer `printf("....blah blah blah....\n");` (in english: "print a complete line").

Comment: in the function ```int maxi``` is it fine to assign a pointer variable to a static variable ```int maxi= *arr``` or should maxi be declared as a double pointer ?